# How can I find the cause of "libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile" messages in my Apache error.log file?

Tags: apache, libpng, error-log

In my Apache `error.log` file I get the following messages:

```
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: cHRM chunk does not match sRGB
```

There is no date, no time, no IP address associated with them, just exactly as you see above.

Most answers on this topic that I saw tell you *how* to convert an image file using ImageMagick, or similar to have correct sRGB profile, or how to remove that profile altogether.  However, I can't change or remove something from an image when such an image has not been identified.

Is there anything I can do to help me find the cause of the above error messages?  Like trigger a stack trace, file name, anything at all that may help me discover the source of those messages?

All of the PNG images in my web application root folder and subfolders appear to be okay when I checked them with ImageMagick's `identify` command

Comment: If your PNG is grayscale, you can get that kind of warning as sRGB profile is not relevant to grayscale images.